# Find range of the function $f(x)=\frac{\left\{x\right\}}{1+(\lfloor x\rfloor)^2}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, maxima-minima, ceiling-and-floor-functions

Find range of the function $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$

$$f(x)=\frac{\left\{x\right\}}{1+(\lfloor x\rfloor)^2}$$

My try:

Obviously range contains zero, since for integers $\left\{x\right\}=0$

If $x$ is not an integer we have $x=n+f$ Then

$$f(n+f)=\frac{f}{1+n^2} \lt 1$$

So range is $\left[0, \:\: 1\right)$

is this right approach?

Comment: What does $\{x\} mean?

Comment: I think it is the decimal part of a number

Comment: It is correct if your fractional part $\{\cdot\}$ is defined as $x-\lfloor x\rfloor$ but sometimes it is defined as $x-\lceil x\rceil$ when $x$ is negative.

Comment: Range is certainly a (*not-necessarily proper*) *subset* of $[0,1)$ using the observations I have heard you state.  Now, see if you can further reason why it is the entire set of $[0,1)$.

Comment: `Obviously range contains zero, since for integers {x}=0` Along the same line of thought, for $0 \le x \lt 1\,$, $f(x)=\ldots$

Answer (score 2):

For negative number $-n-f$,
$$f(-n-f)=\frac{-f}{1+(n+1)^2}$$

$$0\le f<1\Leftrightarrow 0\ge f(-n-f)>\frac{-1}{1+(n+1)^2}\ge-\frac12$$

Therefore, the range is $(-\frac12,1)$.

[image]
[image]

Bonus: $$\int_0^\infty f(x)dx=\frac{\pi \coth \pi +1}4$$